# How to exclude files or folder from eleventy?

Tags: sass, eleventy

I am brand new to Eleventy, and generally everything is going smoothly. I have a simple Eleventy project that uses SCSS for my styles. I have a single `styles/site.scss` file which imports various components from `/styles/components/*.scss`.

When I build or serve the project it **does** transform my SCSS files into CSS, but it also builds and copies over everything to `/styles/components/*.css` which I do not need. These are duplicated bits of code since everyting in them is already included in `/styles/components/site.css` - this is the only generated CSS file I want to include.

Here's what is generated in the `/_site/` folder

[image: Eleventy SCSS file output]

Here is my `.eleventy.js` file

```js
const sass = require("sass");
const path = require("node:path");

module.exports = function (eleventyConfig) {
  eleventyConfig.addPassthroughCopy("src/img");
  eleventyConfig.addPassthroughCopy("src/js");

  eleventyConfig.addTemplateFormats("scss");
  eleventyConfig.addExtension("scss", {
    outputFileExtension: "css",
    compile: function (inputContent, inputPath) {
      let parsedPath = path.parse(inputPath);
      let result = sass.compileString(inputContent, {
        loadPaths: [parsedPath.dir || ".", this.config.dir.includes],
      });

      return () => result.css;
    },
  });

  return {
    dir: {
      input: "src",
    },
  };
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The magic happens in the `compile` function inside `addExtension("scss", { ... })`. This function is called build-time for every `*.scss` file in your project.

The function receives the `inputPath`.

Try checking whether it's a file in a directory you wish to exclude, and if so, just return from the function ([as per documentation](https://www.11ty.dev/docs/languages/custom/#skipping-a-template-from-inside-of-the-compile-function)). For example:

```js
if (inputPath.includes('components')) return;
```

Comment: So this seems to partially work. During a full build - no issues at all. On a `--serve` it does skip copying these files over, but any code changes I make in these files are not happening at all.  It just re-generated the same file regardless of changes I make in any of the `/components/*.scss` files.  It's like I need to detect the build type and only prevent `components` from generating when it's a full build and not a dev `--serve` command

Comment: Looking into this further, the issue I'm having is unrelated to the changes you are proposing here. So your answer actually does work great, but I am just having [this other issue now](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77732974/how-to-make-eleventy-correctly-build-scss-while-in-serve-mode) which I need help with.