# How to make Eleventy correctly build SCSS while in --serve mode?

Tags: sass, eleventy

I have a simple Eleventy project that uses SCSS.

My file structure is like this:

```
src
├─ styles
│  ├─ components
│  │  ├─ _buttons.scss
│  │  ├─ _forms.scss
│  ├─ site.scss
```

When I run the `--serve` CLI option the initial build correctly generates a the `_site/styles/site.css` file. If I make a change to `components/*.scss`,the CLI notifies me that a watched file was changed but the generated `site.css` is not changed at all.

However if I make a change directly to the `site.scss` file or stop the `--serve` process and re-start it, only then will it correctly generate the correct CSS.

Here is my `eleventy.js` file

```js
const sass = require('sass');
const path = require('node:path');

module.exports = function (eleventyConfig) {
  eleventyConfig.addTemplateFormats('scss');
  eleventyConfig.addExtension('scss', {
    outputFileExtension: 'css',
    compile: async function (inputContent, inputPath) {
      let parsedPath = path.parse(inputPath);

      let result = sass.compileString(inputContent, {
        loadPaths: [parsedPath.dir || '.', this.config.dir.includes],
      });

      return async (data) => result.css;
    },
  });

  return {
    dir: { input: 'src' },
  };
};
```

What do I need to change to make this always generate correct CSS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Eleventy documentation](https://www.11ty.dev/docs/languages/custom/#registering-dependencies) again comes to your rescue. :)

You need to add one line inside your `compile` function, before the `return`:

```
this.addDependencies(inputPath, result.loadedUrls);
```

The `result.loadedUrls` is the list of imported files - reported by the SASS compiler. With this `addDependencies` call you pass this list to Eleventy, telling it to watch those files as well, and when they change, rebuild the current file.

Comment: Great, thanks!  I kinda wish this (any my last question) just happened out-of-the-box by default, but thankfully this isn't too much boilerplate to add for every project.  Due to the usage of `this` I cannot make my `compile` function into a `() => {}` arrow function. Not a big deal, but is there another way to access what `this` is?